# Qt: cannot open file for writing

Tags: qt, file, permissions

I try to access a simple text file from a Qt-widget application with the QFile class for reading an writing. Reading the file line by line as a string works fine. But opening it ready to write fails. The following code checks if the file exists and tries to set the proper permissions, but in the end the file won't open.
Here is the failing piece of code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  w.show();

    QFile file(":/test.dat");
    qDebug() << "exists?              " << file.exists();
    qDebug() << "writable?            " << file.isWritable();
    qDebug() << "permissions before?  " << file.permissions();
    qDebug() << "permissions set?     " << file.setPermissions(QFileDevice::WriteOther | QFileDevice::ReadOther);
    qDebug() << "permissions after?   " << file.permissions();

    qDebug() << "opened?              " << file.open(QIODevice::Append);
    qDebug() << "errors?              " << file.errorString();
    qDebug() << "errnum?              " << file.error();
    QTextStream out(&file);
    out << "something to append";
    file.close();

  return app.exec();
}
```

Qt returns this message:

```
exists?               true
writable?             false
permissions before?   QFlags(0x4|0x40|0x400|0x4000)
permissions set?      false
permissions after?    QFlags(0x4|0x40|0x400|0x4000)
opened?               false
errors?               "Unknown error"
errnum?               5
QIODevice::write (QFile, ":/test.dat"): device not open
```

If I change the parameter in the open-function to `QIODevice::ReadOnly` the file is readable without problems, failing with `QIODevice::WriteOnly`. Why doesn't the same thing work for writing as well? Is it the permission? And why don't the permissions change after I called `setPermissions`? I run Qt as root on Ubuntu 14.04. And `test.dat` has full rights `-rwxrwxrwx` owned by user.
Can someone help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author is having Linux-related problem with writing to file created by console process with elevated privileges. I have fully reproduced the problem and when attempted to remove the file with:

```
vi \home\myuser\Documents\f.txt // create file like that from console
rm \home\myuser\Documents\f.txt // now try to remove it from console
```

I got `"rm: remove write-protected regular file "\home\myuser\Documents\f.txt"` and responded "yes" and then the code above shows after creating new file in the context of the program's process:

```
opened?               true
exists?               true
writable?             true
permissions before?   QFlags(0x4|0x20|0x40|0x200|0x400|0x2000|0x4000)
permissions set?      true
permissions after?    QFlags(0x4|0x20|0x40|0x200|0x400|0x2000|0x4000)
errors?               "Unknown error"
errnum?               0
```

> I run Qt Creator as root on Ubuntu 14.04.

It does not ensure the privileges of the program you run from it, I guess. UPDATE: make sure you run the program with appropriate permissions e.g. Root in this case.

Comment: As I mentioned: this does not work for me. I tried all OpenModeFlags that would enable writing but none of them work.

Comment: Oh, right, my overlook. Try the fully qualified OS path. No ~ and no :/" The latter may be interpreted as an internal Qt resource (just a guess). Try to put that file somewhere else as well.

Comment: Thanks, for the hint. I used the fully qualified OS path. If I change the permissions manually the permissions stay that way in the Qt app, but unfortunately the file still can't be opened ready to write.

Comment: Updated my answer. It is process context related privileges set for the file.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
I created a new project and copy pasted the code from the old project. I don't know why, but now everything is working perfectly. Even if I run Qt Creator without root privileges. The only thing I changed is, that the file to write to is not added to the Qt project. Maybe there was a conflict, because the file was still used in Qt Creator but also used by the program. Could this happen?

Comment: Yes, it could. The main (likely the only) reason is complex file rights pertain to certain user and you created the file as 'root'. Should your program run as 'root' there will be no problem but the error message is not telling. You can accept my answer then.